# I am trying to print text in input box in console , problem is I cant see anychanges in my console as I try to type anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the code but the output is nothing as I see

```
import { restaurantList } from "../config";
import { RestrauntCard } from "./Restraunt";
const Body = () => {
  const searchText = "KFC";
  return (
    <>
      <div className="search-container">
        <input
          type="text"
          className="search-input"
          placeholder="Search"
          value={searchText}
          onChange={(e) => console.log(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button className="search-btn"> Search</button>
      </div>
      <div className="restaurant-list">
        {restaurantList.map((restaurant) => {
          return (
            <RestrauntCard {...restaurant.data} key={restaurant.data.id} />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
export default Body;
```

Output in console:
[image: Output Image]

I am trying to print it up in my console to check whether my text is being taken into my input

Comment: yep I tried to write in my Input box , as far as I know nothing would change in my Input box , but it would be changed in my console like this
KFC+any characters I type"

Comment: Hold the searchText in a state variable `const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState("KFC")` and setState the **searchText** in onChange event now try to console in the Body component

Comment: You have a typo here, `onChange={(e) => console.log(e.target.value)}` it should be `onChange="(e) => { console.log(e.target.value); }"` you might need to use quotes

Comment: @DineshMsd it worked , thank you

Answer (score 0):

For testing you can remove `value` attribute. (`value={searchText}`)
As for now value is set and cannot be change.
So if you remove it - you'll see inputs in console

After that I recommend to create state for this value and set changed value into it (to make input [controlled](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)):

```
const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState("KFC");
```

And then use

```
<input
  type="text"
  className="search-input"
  placeholder="Search"
  value={searchText}
  onChange={(e) => setSearchText(e.target.value)}
/>
```